# Create help option for a python script

Tags: python

I have written a script in python which is taking some command line arguments. Now I want to make my script user friendly. So i want to create a help menu for my script.My command line for script to run is-

```
python newcode.py textfile.txt 18ww24 PO .43
```

Now I want something like this-

```
python newcode.py -h
```

And it should display the complete information for the command line options used for the script

I have already read an article which is developing an script separately for help. I want to know Can we give the help option within the main script itself??

> EDIT
>   I have tried using the code given below but it is not working`

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Meaning for each of the Command line arguments')
parser.add_argument('strings', metavar='textfile.txt', type=str, 
               help='log.util file path generated from patch build')
parser.add_argument('strings', metavar='work_week', type=str,
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('strings', metavar='PIF', type=str,
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('strings', metavar='Milestone', type=str,
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('strings',metavar='patch_revid',type=str,
 help='patch_revid')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now when this script is run individually in a seperate file say test.py then passing option as - python test.py -h is giving complete information about the command line arguments as below-

```
usage: help.py [-h] textfile.txt work_week PIF Milestone patch_revid
Meaning for each of the Command line arguments
positional arguments:
textfile.txt  log.util file path generated from patch build
work_week     an integer for the accumulator
PIF           an integer for the accumulator
Milestone     an integer for the accumulator
patch_revid   patch_revid for patch released

optional arguments:
-h, --help    show this help message and exit
```

but when the same code is included in the main script where I want script to perform normal functioning when all the command line arguments are given and if given --help argument then should display the help.

for example my script name is ReadExcel.py then If I do "python ReadExcel.py -h"
then it should display the help.

Comment: As someone said, [know your standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: You copy/pasted the code from an article that contains all the informations you need.

Comment: You get `-h` for free...it's not something you have to write any code for.

Comment: but the problem is it is still not working. I have taken it from an article but it is showing no effect-@bruno desthuilliers

Comment: You need to make sure you call `parser.parse_args()` at some point. But if you do that, you get `-h` for free.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please look into the code now-@Matt Messersmith